# Mean average precision python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have two set of list as follows

> prediction:   [(4268968909,   [955398943,    2529072432,
>   1600413013])]
>
> Truth: [(4268968909, [955398943])]

```
import ml_metrics as metrics
metrics.mapk([Truth],[prediction],2)
```

This gives a value of 0.0. The Map@2 value shouldn't be close to zero.

What is the correct way to produce the right Mean Average Precision at K?

Comment: Those lists look nested to me, do you need to flatten them?

Comment: mean Average Precision in Python - https://github.com/Cartucho/mAP

Answer (score 0):

I think if you change this line:

```
metrics.mapk([Truth],[prediction],2)
```

to this:

```
metrics.mapk(Truth,prediction,2)
```

you will get a MAP@2 value of 0.5.

Let me know if it works for you or not.